# Building Boost.Test from sources : library libboost_unit_test_framework missing

Tags: boost

I am building Boost from sources.
I need the library *libboost_unit_test library* for doing unit tests.
But this library in not generated...
I compile Boost like this :

```
.\bootstrap.bat
.\b2 address-model=64 runtime-link=shared link=shared variant=release stage --stagedir=./stage/x64/Release --build-dir=build/x64/Release
```

I should get *libboost_unit_test_framework-vc140-mt-gd-x64-1_66.lib*...

I cannot find how to build this library...
Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Where are you looking for it?

The naming you used for `--build-dir` suggests that you might be confused about that. `--build-dir` indicates the place to put *temporary* (intermediate) objects, not the completed targets.

The targets are normally under `stage/lib`

Comment: I searched everywhere... I obtain a boost_unit_test_framework-vc140-mt-gd-x64-1_66.lib/dll but not LIBboost_unit_test_framework-vc140-mt-gd-x64-1_66.lib.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sehe : with your answer I have found.
A stupid problem :
- `Libboost_unit_test_framework-vc140-mt-gd-x64-1_66.lib` is for static linking.
- `boost_unit_test_framework-vc140-mt-gd-x64-1_66.lib` is for dynamic linking.

To use dynamic linking I have to add this define in my projet : `#define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK`
And to build the static version I have to use `b2 --link=static`.